# endless request to back-end using useEffect hook React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to make a a request to my back-end so when my component loads it can receive some data to render.

the problem is that the application goes in an infinite loop of requests that consumes resources.

what am I doing wrong?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3005/people", {UUID}).then((response) => {
        const peopleArray = [];
        for (let key in response.data) {
          peopleArray.push({ ...response.data[key] });
        }
        setPeople(peopleArray);
      });
  });
```

Comment: You are missing the second parameter of `useEffect` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect), which is the array of dependences. Whenever each of the dependencies change, the function is ran again. Because you didn't specify any dependency, the function will run forever. If you want to the function to run just once, add `[]` as a second argument. If you want it to run every time `UUID` changes, add `[UUID]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to an array of dependences to useEffect, to only run on the component mounted or any of these dependencies change. as without an array of dependences, it will run with each render, which will cause an infinite loop.

```
      useEffect(() => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3005/people", {UUID}).then((response) => {
        const peopleArray = [];
        for (let key in response.data) {
          peopleArray.push({ ...response.data[key] });
        }
        setPeople(peopleArray);
      });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Documentation](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)
or check this example [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useeffect.asp)

Only run the effect on the initial render:

```
useEffect(() => {
 Axios.post("http://localhost:3005/people", {UUID}).then((response) => {
    const peopleArray = [];
    for (let key in response.data) {
      peopleArray.push({ ...response.data[key] });
    }
    setPeople(peopleArray);
 });
}, []); // <- add empty brackets here
```